# Call prototype another prototype in new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, prototype, prototypejs

This returns back thisFunction.weather.day() is undefined.. Why? Am i doing this correct?

```
 'use scrict';

    var thisFunction = function(){this.event(); };

    thisFunction.prototype.weather = function(){

        this.day = "Cloudy";

    };

    thisFunction.prototype.event = function(){

        console.log(thisFunction.weather().day);

    };

    var g = new thisFunction();
```

Im trying to call the weather function inside of event. As you can see at the bottom theres a new var g that equals new thisFunction(). If I call the weather function inside event thisFunction.prototype.weather().day is undefined. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thisFunction` is your constructor function.

It does not have a `.weather()` method.  So, `thisFunction.weather` is `undefined` and `thisFunction.weather()` is an error.

The `.weather()` method is on the prototype which means its on instances of `thisFunction`, not on the constructor itself.  So, in your code, you could do:

```
 g.weather()
```

Or, inside of the `.event()` method, you could do this:

```
thisFunction.prototype.event = function(){

    console.log(this.weather());
};
```

To make `this.weather().day` work, you'd have to `return this` from the `.weather()` method.

```
thisFunction.prototype.weather = function(){

    this.day = "Cloudy";
    return this;

};

thisFunction.prototype.event = function(){

    console.log(this.weather().day);

};
```

Comment: Ok, how am I able to get weather.day outside of a prototype? Outside of the prototype I included var thisf = new thisFunction();

Comment: @NodeBeginner - You just use `g.day` in your example in your question.

Comment: @NodeBeginner - It's right there in your question: `var g = new thisFunction();`

Comment: OK gotcha Thanks!, and mybad, im working on code and the one i provided was just an example. I forgot i had that, even though i said thisf for another example lol